# How to declare static variables in a class for use in various classes in swift

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I want to declare these variables in a class separately for use in all other classes.

For example I want to declare
var account, username, password.

How can i do it please ????

Answer (score 1):

To declare a static variable use the `static` keyword for static variables in a `Struct` or `Enum` and for class variables in a `Class`.

For example:

```
Class myClass {
    static var myVar = 0
}

Struct myStruct {
    static var myVar = "MyVar"
}

Enum myEnum {
    case Case1, Case2

    static var myVar = 10.0
}
```

When accessing static variables you need to make sure you prefix them with the name of the `Class`, `Struct` or `Enum`. For example:

```
myClass.myVar = 1
```

Or

```
println(myStruct.myVar)
```

Comment: i'm trying to use it like it, but it says that "statics properties may only be declared in a type". My idea is declare three static variables together (account, username, password). Please help

Comment: Could you post the code that's giving you that error as an edit to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Declare class  like it:

```
class User {

    var account:Int
    var username :String
    var password:String

    init(account:Int, username:String, password: String){
      self.account = account
      self.username = username
      self.password = password
}
```

}

```
class UserTest{

   func createUser(account:Int, username:String, password:String){

    var user = User(account: account, username: username, password: password)

   }

}
```